# Different way of expressing variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am having trouble with the following statement (from one of the answers from SOA exam, don't worry about the question as it has no bearing on the question I am asking).

> The marginal distribution of X has probability $1/5 + a$ at $0$, $2a + b$ at $1$, and $1/5 + a$ at $2$. Due to symmetry, the mean is $1$ ***and so the variance is $(0-1)^2 (1/ 5+a ) +(1- 0)^2 (1/ 5 +a) = 2/5+2a$***

I do not recognize this expression for variance from anywhere that I remember. The only one I am familiar with is $${E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}$$

Can somebody please explain to me this other expression that is being used here, $(0-1)^2 (1/ 5+a ) +(1- 0)^2 (1/ 5 +a)$, or even just provide a link?

Comment: Have you understood why $a=b$?

Comment: It is not, I think it was a typo.

Comment: No it isn´t a typo

Comment: Well, here is a link to the question,how does $a=b$?. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfhjE.png

Comment: After I have looked at the joint pdf I recognised that we cannot say for sure that $a=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[(X-E[X])^2] &= E[X^2-2XE[X]+(E[X])^2] \\
&=E[X^2]-2E[X]E[X]+(E[X])^2 \\
&=E[X^2]-2(E[X])^2+(E[X])^2 \\
&=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 \\
\end{align}

They use an alternative expression for the variance which is just $E[((X-E[X])^2] $.

We have three values, $x_1, x_2, x_3$ where $x_2$ is the mean and $(x_3-x_2)^2=(x_1-x_2)^2$ in this question.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind explaining a bit more, I think I understand $(0-1)^2 (1/ 5+a )$ but I am still confused about $(1- 0)^2 (1/ 5 +a)$, what does the $0$ represent?

Comment: I think they use symmetry about the mean. There are two values that is not equal to the mean, of which the distance to the mean is equal.

Comment: thanks callculus.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(0-1)^2 (1/ 5+a )+(2-1)^2 (1/ 5 +a)$ as that would be consistent with the alternative expression you posted, $E[((X-E[X])^2]$?

Comment: yes, just that by symmetry, you could have just written it as $2(0-1)^2(1/5+a)$ as well.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you are saying now. Thank you!